# Rotating bone at paused Gameplay in SceneView not possible

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a character that plays an animation that is coming from an animator.

In the SceneView, I can not rotate any bone but the hip. Not by the Gizmo, and not be the Inspector.

Even when the gameplay is played, I can not rotate any body but the hip.
If I disable the animator, I can rotate other bones.

What might be the reason why I can not do so?

Comment: It is because the Animator controller is constantly overwriting the transform values of the rig.

Comment: Even when the gameplay is paused?